# Missing table in Visual FoxPro DB

Tags: oledb, visual-foxpro

I'm using VFPOLEDB to connect to an VFP database (directory of dbf files).

Once connected, I manually create a table using:

```
create dbf critera(field_name c(30))
```

At this point, I verify a new dbf file is created in the database directory.  I then try to query the new table, it should return no rows.

```
select * from criteria
```

I am presented with the following error:

```
File "criteria.dbf" does not exit.
```

Strange, eh?

So I manually delete the DBF file (VFPOLEDB doesn't support drop) and then run the following query.

```
create db criteria(field_name c(30)); select * from criteria
```

And get no error, no results returned as expected.

What gives?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, (could be a type-o), you had

```
create dbf Critera  (missing the "i")
```

and then

```
select * from Criteria (has the "i")
```

If not that... for your connection string, are you just connecting to the PATH that the .dbf files will be located, or are you explicitly connecting to a path and database.

If just a path

```
string YourVFPConnectionString =
   "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=c:\\SomePath\\WhereDataIs\\";
```

Or with a specific database container

```
string YourVFPConnectionString =
   "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=c:\\SomePath\\WhereDataIs\\YourDatabase.dbc";
```

It might be easier to test just by pointing to the directory.  The VFP OleDB provider will consider the path the root for any tables queried vs a full .dbc (database container) which could give you access to other stored procedures and such.

The OleDb doesn't support "DROP TABLE".  You can still delete a file by running an ERASE "Criteria.dbf" via the OleDbCommand's  ExecuteNonQuery()

As for the last one, VFP doesn't utilize the ";" as a break between statements like other SQL engines do where you could send a series of queries all together one after another.  ";" in VFP is considered a "this command continues on the next line", and should have thrown an exception is it wouldn't have been able to process it.